# Is Dragonblood Sorcerer worth it?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, sorcerer, class-feature, dragons

Dragon Magic presents a system of substitute levels of various classes for characters with the Dragonblood subtype. One of which, Dragonblood Sorcerer, provides the following benefits:

1st level: Knowledge(arcana) Insight Bonus +2 (given at each substitution level, stacking up to 6), Draconic Heritage (replaces Familiar)

4th level: turns one spell not of highest casting level into spell-like ability with 3 uses per day at cost of one spell slot of the spell's level and of the higher level.

7th: new spells for the level will be the following:

For good-aligned characters:
 Bless (1st level), fog cloud, resist energy (2nd level), fly (3rd level)

For evil-aligned characters:
 charm (1st level), darkness, resist energy (2nd level), suggestion (3rd level)

Now, I'm no expert, so I really can't tell if this is worth taking or not. Could I get some professional advice on this?

And for the record, this is going to be used on a Spellscale sorcerer/fatespinner/fortune's friend(/prestige bard?) with a mostly support-oriented role.

Answer (score 2):

First, remember that substitution levels can be taken in whole or in part; you can take one of these substitutions and not the others, if you wish.

### Dragonblood Sorcerer 1

Familiars are generally better than Draconic Heritage; only do that if there are particular feats that require it that you wanted to take. I don’t remember there being any that were particularly good, but maybe there’s something that interests you or whatever.

### Dragonblood Sorcerer 4

The 4th-level substitution depends a lot on what spell it is. But at 4th level, you only have 2nd-level slots, so you’re talking about a 1st-level spell that you’re casting thrice per day. There are some great 1st-level spells but I cannot think of any that I’d want to cast three times a day, every day. Besides, you could always take that feat that allows you to split up your spell slots if you *really wanted*; you’d be able to trade a 2nd-level slot for two 1st-level slots, and then you’re not restricted to that particular spell.

**But**, do note the special rules for spell-like abilities, versus actual spells. Most importantly, they don’t have any components: no gestures, no chants, no materials, no foci, and no experience cost. If you can find a 1st-level spell that’s got an annoying gold or XP cost... that could be worth it. But as a 1st-level spell, that’s not exactly thrilling. The only thing I can think of is *identify*, and there are plenty of easier ways to get that (Artificer’s Monocle in *Magic Item Compendium* is my choice).

This ability gets a whole lot better if you can somehow delay Sorcerer 4 until after you have higher-level spells. Getting a free *identify* is OK; getting a free *forcecage* or *legend lore* or *true seeing* is rather cool. But I cannot think of too many ways to do that without losing spellcasting levels or getting DMGs thrown at you.

### Dragonblood Sorcerer 7

You get one more 2nd-level spell than you otherwise would. On the other hand, you don’t get to choose, and your pre-selected spells are not so great. You probably wanted *fly* no matter what, and *resist energy* is pretty good, but *bless* is garbage, *darkness* is only OK, and *charm* and *suggestion* both suffer for being [Mind-Affecting] (which way too many things are immune to). I suggest a pass on this level.

Comment: Thought they sounded rather off. I wanted to avoid Familiar if I could so I wouldn't have any obligation to take more Sorcerer levels than what I needed to qualify for my prestige classes, but if Draconic Heritage-related feats don't catch my interest, I could settle for having a weak familiar. The spell-like ability spell can be swapped out at higher levels, and level 7 does seem useless, then.